# Expect Argument Type to be integer but getting id instead

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsinvocation

I'm using the `forwardInvocation:` feature of objective-c and I need to know what **type** of argument the method received.  In my example I'm passing it an `int` but `getArgumentTypeAtIndex:` tells me it's an `id` instead. Here's a simple example:

```
@interface Do : NSObject
+ (void) stuff:(int)x;
@end
@implementation Do
+ (NSMethodSignature *) methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    NSMethodSignature* signature = [super methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    if (!signature)
        signature = [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(forwardInvocation:)];
    return signature;
}

+ (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)i
{
    const char* argType = [i.methodSignature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:2];
    NSLog(@"%s == %s", argType, @encode(id)); // @ == @
    NSLog(@"%s == %s", argType, @encode(int)); // @ == i
}
@end
```

Here's how I call it:

```
[Do stuff:123];
```

Any idea why I'm not getting `id` instead of `int` as the type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have actually have a `stuff:` method on the class so `methodSignatureForSelector:` will return `nil` - it looks like you discovered that and so implemented your own version, but that fails on the `super` call and so ends up returning the signature of `forwardInvocation:` - which is not what you want!

To get around this you either need to direct the `methodSignatureForSelector:` to a class which has the selector, or use a protocol - if a class implements a protocol then it will return the signature for any methods in that protocol even if the methods are not actually implemented by that class.

Here is your sample using a protocol:

```
@protocol DoProtocol
@optional
+ (void) stuff:(int)x;
@end

@interface Do : NSObject<DoProtocol>
@end

@implementation Do

+ (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)i
{
   const char* argType = [i.methodSignature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:2];
   NSLog(@"%s == %s", argType, @encode(id)); // @ == @
   NSLog(@"%s == %s", argType, @encode(int)); // @ == i
}

@end
```

The `@optional` avoids any compiler warnings for unimplemented methods. The default implementation of `methodSignatureForSelector:` (from `NSObject`) will return a valid signature obtained from the protocol, and so `forwardInvocation:` will be called.

Comment: This works, but in my case I'd need the protocol to be added with a category, not on the original `@interface` declaration. For whatever reason that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I ended up pulling the signature directly from the protocol: `[NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:protocol_getMethodDescription(@protocol(...), selector, 0, 0).types]`

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can get it past the compiler, whatever you pass as an argument will be interpreted as such at runtime - you could declare that a function takes an `NSNumber`, but it you pass a `UITableView` to it, it's `class` will still be a `UITableView`.